# How do I contact another user privately?

Tags: feature-request, user-ids

Many users on this site use their real identity.  So, via google or a linked website, it is usually easy to find the contact details of a fellow user.  However, in cases when users wish -- for whatever reason -- to keep their identity secret, what is the protocol for private contact?  (This is not a cryptography question, btw.)

This is somewhat related to [the question on using actual names](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/on-using-actual-names).  Adding a private email function has its issues and one of these might be that it removes one less incentive for giving your true identity.

This question occurred to me while answering [When should you say what you know?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/when-should-you-say-what-you-know/2361#2361).

Comment: “(This is not a cryptography question, btw.)”  I cannot help imagining that someone will post a cryptography question with exactly the same title on the parent site. :)

Comment: By the way, lack of private messaging seems to be a deliberate choice.  A request for it has been declined on Meta Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Hm... maybe it is a cryptography question after all.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Delving further through that link (thanks!), I found the suggestion (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/1043#1043) for an opt-in shielded email function the most sensible, and still within the spirit of open and collaborative efforts.

Answer (score 9):

If people don't give their contact details, and if you don't want to answer publicly, then simply **don't do anything**. Don't worry about it. It's their fault and their loss.

Answer (score -2):

Stack Exchange sites are focused on the learning and information aspect of Q&A, not the personal interactions of most social-networking sites. Any communications that are focused on solving the problem should not be conducted privately. **Those interactions should be available to the benefit of everyone else.** If the communication is of a more private or social nature... well, that's just not what the site is about.

There are no options to contact a user who does not wish to be contacted. If a user wishes to be contacted, they can leave that information in their public profile.

Comment: I wasn't asking if we could turn this site into the facebook or myspace of theoretical computer science.  There are plenty of concrete academic- and research-related reasons (i.e. not the desire to poke or whatever they do on those other sites) why one may wanted to contact another user privately, one of which I referenced to in the question.

Comment: It seems that the TCS site is a bit different than other stackexchange sites.  I can imagine a question on modeling turning into a full-blown research project that the question poster might want to work on with, for example, the person who provided the best partial answer.  This isn't a cooking site where questions can be answered quickly by a community, nor does it seem right that once a question is posed it shouldn't be "privately" worked on...